# Can Active Directory notify my on changes?

Tags: active-directory, replication

We have a corporate Active Directory and a secondary service that contains user profiles from Active Directory. We have a regular Sync Operation that copies stuff from Active Directory to our profile service every X hours.

I wonder if there is a better way that doesn't require me to poll Active Directory, but rather something that allows Active Directory to notify my app or my app to subscribe to something? Like me participating in Directory Replication without actually being a domain controller (or running AD, for that matter)

Comment: DC replication isn't a "push notification", it acts on a schedule/timer as well.  It only replicates the changed attributes (latest changes), but still on a schedule.

Comment: does this service happen to be an ms sql based processes, if so you can create a linked query into AD.